# Express.js how to make html render on client side with response.render?

Tags: javascript, html, express, pug

I have basic express js application with following route:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){
        res.render('login');
    });
```

It works fine - after logging into main page on my localhost, html from login.pug is nicely rendered on client side. However when my app runs, sometimes I want to render another pug file, when there already is html rendered on client side:

```
app.get('/dashboard', function(req, res){

    res.render('dashboard', {user: req.query.login});
});
```

But when get request is send on`'dashboard'`path, nothing happens. As I understand, this happens because `res.render` just parses `pug` file into HTML and sends it to client as plain string (which I can inspect in browser developers tool, when I check AJAX response I see exactly rendered HTML).

Now my question is: **is there a way to render HTML from res.render in client automatically? So on server side I just write `res.render('template')` and on client side page is re-rendered without handling the response?**

I know I can clear whole DOM and append received string into document.body, I know also that I can make a POST form request and then page will be re-rendered automatically, but I want to avoid both solutions (don't ask why).

Thank you for help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your Javascript sends an Ajax request, the response from that Ajax request is just returned back to your Javascript.  That's it.  The browser does not show anything.  If you want to do something with that response, then it is the responsibility of your Javascript to do something with it (insert it in the page to show it, etc...).

If what you really want is that you want the browser to actually go to the `/dashboard` URL and then show that page, then your Javascript can just do:

```
window.location = '/dashboard';
```

This will tell the browser to fetch the contents of that URL, it will make a request to your server, your server will return the rendered HTML and the browser will display it in the page and show `/dashboard` as the URL in the browser bar.  That should do everything you want.

So, it's totally up to your Javascript.  Pick the right tool for the job.  Either fetch data for your Javascript with an Ajax call and process the result in your Javascript or instruct the browser to load a new page.  One or the other.

> But when get request is send on'dashboard'path, nothing happens. As I understand, this happens because res.render just parses pug file into HTML and sends it to client as plain string (which I can inspect in browser developers tool, when I check AJAX response I see exactly rendered HTML).

Yes, that what Ajax requests do.  They fetch content from the server and return the data back to your Javascript (and only to your Javascript).

> is there a way to render HTML from res.render in client automatically?

Yes, use `window.location = '/dashboard';` from your Javascript.

> So on server side I just write res.render('template') and on client side page is re-rendered without handling the response?

Not from an ajax call.  Ajax calls never automatically display content.  Never.  Ajax calls are programmatic requests that return data to your script.  That's what they are.  But, yes from Javascript you can cause content to be automatically displayed by setting `window.location` to a new URL.

Comment: This doesn't really solve my problem. I want to implement user sessions, and I need redirecting from server side. For example if session expired, in express top middleware I'd call res.redirect('/login') which would call res.render('login'). That's all happening on server side, client isn't aware of that. If I just manipulate DOM/window location, on every ajax call to server I should check if session is still valid? This really can't be handled in other way?

Comment: @Furman - It's kind of agonizing here when your question doesn't really spell out your real problem to solve.  I answered what you originally asked.  Ajax calls don't render in the browser by themselves, ever.  If you want to spell out a completely different question, then please spell it out in a new question.  But, you can't ask an Ajax call to do something it was never designed to do.  A server response to an Ajax call can't affect the browser display or URL by itself.  To do so, it needs cooperating Javascript processing the Ajax response IN the browser.

Comment: @Furman - FYI, it's only a few lines of client Javascript code to process a JSON response from an Ajax call and see that the server is instructing the client-side Javascript to set `window.location = someURLInTheResponse` if you choose to implement that.

Comment: @Furman - And, no you don't check session auth client-side.  That's a server-side function - always.  You've exposed about 10% of your overall problem here so we can't really help any further with the data we have.  This question as asked has been answered.  Please start a new question where you include a much more detail description of the whole problem you're trying to solve and then we can perhaps help you figure out how it should be designed.

Comment: Well you're right, I didn't clarified in my question what really my goal was, which probably was misleading. I wanted to avoid checking session (I mean, checking ajax response if client should redirect due to inactive session) but I see now it is not possible. It's still a bit pain, because I need to check ajax response for active session in every single AJAX request. Still thank you for help and your time.

Comment: @Furman - You can just make a utility function that makes your ajax call and checks the response and sets `window.location` if the response says the user isn't logged in.  You can still do it in one place with a common function that all your ajax calls use.

Comment: Yes I already solved it that way. Still for me it feels a bit messy. But I'm still a novice, I'll get used to it :)